# Google translate toolbar Disable

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, google-translate

I'm doing Web development.
The Google translate toolbar when using Andoroid is disturbing, so I'd like to prevent it from displaying, but it did not disappear .

I entered the following code in the HTML header, but it can not control it well.

```
<meta name = "google" value = "notranslate">
<meta http-equiv = "content-language" content = "ja">
```

When displaying the corresponding page on the PC, the Google  translate toolbar is not displayed.
As for the composition of the site, when you press the A' button on page A, the page of C is displayed via redirect.html (destination check) of B.
The problem here is that the Google translate toolbar will be displayed to the C page when using Android.
If i enter the URL of C page directly on the address bar of Android , the Google translate toolbar will not be displayed.

```
<meta name = "google" value = "notranslate">
<meta http-equiv = "content-language" content = "ja">
```

This code of it was described on both B and C pages, but there was no effect.
What I want to do is not to refuse translation, but to hide (deactivate) the toolbar.

Comment: @RobC Thanks, I verified it, but it did not go well.The browser I check on Android is Chrome.